# Two orders being submitted after checkout

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments, checkout

I am with an issue that after I submit a payment the order is being submitted twice. There are some cases that if I load the application for the first time in my device it will be charged once. However, since it is done more than once there will have more than one charge for the same order.

```
# Create your views here.
stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET


@login_required()
def checkout(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # call the two forms that will be used
        order_form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        payment_form = MakePaymentForm(request.POST)

        # Then will check if both forms are valid if yes, save
        if order_form.is_valid() and payment_form.is_valid():
            order = order_form.save(commit=False)
            order.date = timezone.now()
            order.save()

            cart = request.session.get('cart', {})
            total = 0
            for id, quantity in cart.items():
                destination = get_object_or_404(Destinations, pk=id)
                total += quantity * destination.price
                order_line_item = OrderLineItem(
                    order=order,
                    destination=destination,
                    quantity=quantity
                )
                order_line_item.save()

            try:
                customer = stripe.Charge.create(
                    amount=int(total * 100),
                    currency="EUR",
                    description=request.user.email,
                    card=payment_form.cleaned_data['stripe_id'],
                )
            except stripe.error.CardError:
                messages.error(request, "Your card was declined!")

            if customer.paid:
                messages.error(request, "You have successfully paid")
                request.session['cart'] = {} #clear the cart in session
                return redirect(reverse('destination'))
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Unable to take payment")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "We were unable to take a payment with that card!")
    else:
        payment_form = MakePaymentForm()
        order_form = OrderForm()
    return render(request, "checkout.html", {"order_form": order_form, "payment_form": payment_form, "publishable": settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE})
```

Since it is a recycled code from the bootcamp I am doing I have tried to fix the second if on `order.save()` and add it after the `if customer.paid:` but I am getting error.

[image: django admin/orders]

Comment: Have you checked your AJAX/HTTP Request isn't being sent twice?

Comment: How can I do it since I cant see the error on terminal. The only thing I can see that is related to stripe is a message in the chrome console `(index):2 It looks like Stripe.js was loaded more than one time. Please only load it once per page.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely (as mentioned in the comments) your client-side code is sending more than one request to create a charge.  Ideally you should figure out why that's happening, but you can also use [Idempotency Keys](https://stripe.com/docs/api/idempotent_requests) to solve it too.

Comment: I had a look at the information that you gave me about idempotency. However, I took a day just to analyse and fix this bug and I found that was I loading the `Stripe.publishableKey` twice. One in the `base.html` and another into the `checkout.html`. I got this issue once I checked the chrome console and got a message that stripe was loaded twice. So, I removed it from the checkout page and just kept the stripe key in the `base.html` page and problem solved.